# $U = \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}$. What does it do geometrically to a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, plane-geometry

Let $i$ to be a matrix such that $$i = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\  -1& 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Then what does $ U = \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}$ do to a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I think it's a rotation, but I struggle to justify it or disprove it.

Comment: It's a rotation by an angle $\theta$. Note that any point on $\Bbb{R}^2$ can be represented by a complex number $re^{i\xi}$ and multiplying it by $e^{i\theta}$ just gives $re^{i(\theta+\xi)}$, which is just the complex number rotated through an angle $\theta$

Comment: Have you tried computing the matrix $e^{i\theta}$?